# Python pandas conditional column creation with aggregates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a column that returns True if the P/E is in the lower quartile of all P/E in my dataframe. Below is what i have done so far.

First i defined a function:

```
def pe_cond(df):
    if df['P/E'] <= df['P/E'].quantile(0.1):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Secondly, i tried to apply it to my dataframe

```
df['pe_cond'] = df.apply(pe_cond, axis=1)
```

However i get the below error:

```
AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'quantile'", u'occurred at index 0')
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `df['pe_cond'] = (df['P/E'] <= df['P/E'].quantile(0.1)).astype(int)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment this worked a treat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't do this in a repl quite yet but this may work for you

```
mask = df['P/E'] <= df['P/E'].quantile(0.1)
df.loc[mask, 'pe_cond'] = 1
df.loc[~mask, 'pe_cond'] = 0
```

This is using `.loc` to find the subset of the `DataFrame` that fulfills the logic defined in the `mask` variable. The `~` (unary) operator negates that. So essentially, where the condition is true give it a 1. Where the condition is false give it a 0.

-- Edit -- 
You should totally use @djk47463 comment. It's very concise.

```
df['pe_cond'] = (df['P/E'] <= df['P/E'].quantile(0.1)).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks @djk47463 and Orenshi this was very helpful and works like a charm saves me lot of time not having to define all those functions